# unable to give margin to time element

Tags: html, css

Here's my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>CSS Article3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/article3.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <time datetime="2015-11-23">November 23 2015</time>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is my CSS code:

```
    time{
         border: 1px solid black;
         margin-top: 30px;
         }
```

I want to give this time element a margin at top. To drag it down but it just sits there no matter how much margin I give. Also the margin that I give goes beyond the top of the page instead of pushing this element down. I can give padding to the body and get it done but why cant I do this by giving a margin to the time element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's how `inline` elements works. Make it a `block` element or an `inline-block` element to make it work:

```
time {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 30px; /** now work **/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u9k04tv6/1/

Answer (score 3):

`time` seems to be an inline element. Inline Elements don't respect margin settings.

Change the `display` of time element to `inline-block` or `block`

Comment: That's correct. Inline elements doesn't affect to the height of the line margins nor paddings.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the time with `position: absolute;`

```
time{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-top: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u9k04tv6/

Comment: Not a good solution. This is tricky and cause problems of content. Use position absolute if you understand how it works.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, I know it could be problems with the content if you do not know how to use it but in this case he only wants to get a `margin-top` from the document (at least what I can understand from the question) so it will catch the first relative/absolute parent or the html tag instead. It is why in this case I use `position: absolute`, because it will be positioned taking as reference the html tag. I am not an expert of CSS and I am learning by myself so please correct me if I said something wrong.

Comment: If `margin` works with `position: absolute` it's because absolute positioning pulls out of the normal flow the element and **converts it to a block element**, so margin works, but when OP will try to add your code to a real project, all can crash. Just transform to a block element, don't change the position, it's not for this kind of things. Good luck in your learning proccess :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thank you for the explanation. I am glad to learn new concepts :)

Comment: I edit the answer because I change my downvote to an upvote. See you soon :)